# I am using Android Studio and I am a beginner. Please and suggest solution for the following error

Tags: android

I am getting this error message:

Android resource linking failed
\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:11: error: unexpected element  found in .

The complete code is

```
<manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.MyPlace">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
        tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.TollGate"
    tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent">
    <activity
        android:name=".PlaceListActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AddPlacesActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: You can create a new project and see the manifest how it looks like. You have 2 manifest tags which is not correct. Also you're closing your manifest tag before application, but application needs to be inside the manifest tag

Comment: Remove tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent" from Internet permission.

Comment: @HaykMkrtchyan If I have to remove one manifest tag, which one you suggest?

Comment: Jongwoo Jang already answered

Comment: @Hayk Mkrtchyan ok Thanx...it worked

Answer (score 0):

You have two manifest tags. Try this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    package="com.example.MyPlace">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TollGate"
        tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent">
        <activity
            android:name=".PlaceListActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AddPlacesActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```